# The easiest way to implement in Angular what was possible in AngularJS with directive + template?

Tags: angular

In AngularJS I could use the directive + template to split a huge HTML file with multiple tabs each tab's HTML to be in its own HTML which was then dynamically loaded into the main HTML based on some ng-show condition.

The AngularJS code was something like this

```
directive('generalsettingstab', () => {
   return {
     template: tabGeneralSettingsTemplate
   }
 })
 .directive('connectionsettingstab', () => {
   return {
     template: tabConnectionSettingsTemplate
   }
 })
 .directive('emailmessagetab', () => {
   return {
     template: tabEmailMessageTemplate
   }
 })

<uib-tab heading="General Settings" ng-show="$ctrl.shouldTabBeVisible('generalsettingstab');">

<generalsettingstab></generalsettingstab>

</uib-tab>

<uib-tab heading="Connection Settings" ng-show="$ctrl.shouldTabBeVisible('connectionsettingstab');">

<connectionsettingstab></connectionsettingstab>

</uib-tab>

<uib-tab heading="Email Message" ng-show="$ctrl.shouldTabBeVisible('emailmessagetab');">

<emailmessagetab></emailmessagetab>

</uib-tab>
```

This way each of the different TAB html files would use the same JS controller. This was a good mechanism to split a big HTML into smaller pieces and re-compose together the UI at run-time.

I am trying to implement something similar in the Angular (6/7) but my current difficulty is that the template argument was removed from the Angular @Directive so duplicating what was possible in AngularJS is not immediately possible in Angular. I also tried using a separate (dummy/light) @Component with its own template but this did not work because when, in one of the tab's HTML, I tried to access a TypeScript function I got an error "undefined function" (because each component will get its own separate controller - and my intention is to use a common Controller for all tabs).

I believe something might be possible with angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet but it all seems too complicated vs. the initial solution in AngularJS.

**What is the simplest / most straightforward way in the new Angular to split a big HTML into smaller separate template files which can be then re-constructed at run-time?** (and all HTMLs to be part of the same big / parent component UI component). I believe a simple solution should be possible in Angular because this is a common requirement to split a big UI into smaller HTML files.

P.S: In Angular 6/7 The individual tab's HTML is loaded using raw-loader like this

import * as tabGeneralSettingsTemplate from '!raw-loader!./templates/tab-general-settings.html';

Answer (score 0):

I know you would prefer to keep the same mental model and match features ... but sometimes that becomes difficult with AngularJS -> Angular because of the differences in how they work.

With that said, I would suggest building a separate component for each tab. I have an example I could provide if it would help.

You can then route to each tab's component to display the tab.

In terms of sharing a "controller", consider building a service with the common functionality. Each of the "tab" components can then access this shared service to access shared data or functions.

This may not be the `easiest` approach, but it could be a `solid` approach.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DeborahK I'll keep this in mind as a possible option / alternative.

Meawhile, on the individual tabs HTML code, I managed to "reuse" the main ConfigurationComponent functions (code) using *class TabGeneralSettingsComponent **extends ConfigurationComponent** {}*

Now, only for the prototyping phase seems to work fine but while the application will grow I might encounter some issues with this approach. Probably each tab will create a separate object instance of the ConfigurationComponent which is not exactly what I want and which could generate some performance issues (or even strange bugs) - I will keep an eye on this aspect.

So, if anyone else is interested, this is the current approach.

```
import * as tabGeneralSettingsTemplate from '!raw-loader!./templates/tab-general-settings.html';

@Component({
  selector: 'generalsettingstab',
  template: tabGeneralSettingsTemplate
})
class TabGeneralSettingsComponent extends ConfigurationComponent {}
```